# How to making sure class properties is of correct type in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, types

I'm just getting started with making some more serious projects in javascript, and I'm feeling like the typelessness is becoming a bit of an issue. Specifically, I often find that my classes are being initiated with the wrong types, a bug that preferably should be easy to fix but sometimes costs me lots of time. That is why I would like to know: are there any practices in javascript for asserting that a class property is of the correct type? Like in this example (a should always be a string, b should always be an instance of the class Bar, and c should always be a number):

```
class Foo {
    constructor(a,b,c){
        if(typeof a !== "string"){
            throw "Wrong type";
        }
        this.a = a;
        if(!(b instanceof Bar)){
            throw "Wrong type";
        }
        this.b = b;
        if(typeof c !== "number"){
            throw "Wrong type";
        }
        this.c = c;
    }

    setA(a){
        if(typeof a !== "string"){
            throw "Wrong type";
        }
        this.a = a;
    }

    setB(b){
        if(!(b instanceof Bar)){
            throw "Wrong type";
        }
        this.b = b;
    }

    setC(c){
        if(typeof c !== "number"){
            throw "Wrong type";
        }
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

This feels like a bad way to do this, as it's very cumbersome and repetitive, and it also feels weird to just throw "Wrong type". Are there any best practices regarding this? Is this problem usually just ignored?

I have tried to research this, but haven't been able to find something even mentioning this problem.

Also, I'm aware that this potentially is quite a subjective question, and might not be suited for this site. In that case, does anyone have any pointers to where I should be asking this kind of question?

Comment: Use typescript.

Comment: 1) I've hardly come across JavaScript that needs to be typed (it would generally have to be a large codebase).  2) Typescript would be your friend here 3) I would typically recommend strongly typed JavaScript, if the development team is familiar with it, or for performance gains; otherwise, it can get in the way -- In your case this sounds more like an X/Y problem.  Instead of checking the type, can you check the function and throw an error then? `try { a.forEach } catch(e) { console.log(e) }`

Comment: @BotNet What do you mean by "strongly typed JavaScript"? Isn't Javascript per definition a weakly typed language? Or is "strongly typed JavaScript" just another way to say "TypeScript"?

Comment: @Istlemin strongly-typed refers to imposing a type-based requirement (or erroring) as opposed to "loosely" typed which implicitly determines the type and may bend/change typing based on new assignments.  Typescript is just one of a potentially infinite number of implementations that enforces strong typing, it's just the popular and leading one, which is why it is recommended.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing / https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/strongly-typed

Comment: JavaScript at its core is weakly typed, but variable types exist and as you begin checking the type and instituting your own try/catch/throw, you are making your code stronger typed. -- Typescript is a superset of JavaScript, which means it will eventually be broken down to JavaScript.  It already has the persistent rules imposing the typing, which makes it a strongly-typed language.  What makes TypeScript especially great is that can act as the bridge between JavaScript and WebAssembly, for all the performance nuts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generify it a bit and use real getters / setters to beautify the whole thing a bit:

```
const assert = (val, is) => { 
   if(typeof value !== is) 
     throw new Error(`WrongType: ${val} for ${is}`);
};

class Test {
  constructor(a) {
    this.a = a;
  }

  set a(v) { assert(v, "string"); this._a = v; }
  get a(){ return this._a; }
}
```

But if thats still to ugly, just use typescript or flow.